# PulseAudio on Cygwin: Failed to create secure directory: Unknown error 13

Tags: cygwin, pulse-audio

I am unable to run PulseAudio on Cygwin.

**Operating System:** Windows 8 Pro 64 bit

**Cygwin Setup.exe Version:** 2.831 (64 bit)

**PulseAudio Version:** 2.1-1

When I run:

```
pulseaudio -vv
```

this is the output:

```
D: [(null)] core-util.c: setpriority() worked.
I: [(null)] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [(null)] main.c: This is PulseAudio 2.1
D: [(null)] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
D: [(null)] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -ggdb -O2 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/pulseaudio/pulseaudio-2.1-1/build=/usr/src/debug/pulseaudio-2.1-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/pulseaudio/pulseaudio-2.1-1/src/pulseaudio-2.1=/usr/src/debug/pulseaudio-2.1-1 -Wall -W -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wvla -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option
D: [(null)] main.c: Running on host: CYGWIN_NT-6.2 x86_64 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:37
D: [(null)] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
I: [(null)] main.c: Page size is 65536 bytes
D: [(null)] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [(null)] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [(null)] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [(null)] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [(null)] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [(null)] main.c: Machine ID is 5d8bd07cb924c67197184e42527f2603.
E: [(null)] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory: Unknown error 13
```

When I instead run

```
pulseaudio -vv --start
```

the output is this:

```
E: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory: Unknown error 13
W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
E: [(null)] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
```

When I ran `strace pulseaudio -vv`, the last few lines in the output were:

```
418 2049456 [main] pulseaudio 6196 stat64: entering
57 2049513 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: src /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin
49 2049562 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin = normalize_posix_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin)
45 2049607 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin)
51 2049658 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin'
52 2049710 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
57 2049767 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin, dst C:\Users\Nithin, flags 0x4022, rc 0
197 2049964 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin)
99 2050063 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: not a symlink
77 2050140 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin, 0x239500) (0x404022)
57 2050197 [main] pulseaudio 6196 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\Users\Nithin), has_acls(1)
64 2050261 [main] pulseaudio 6196 build_fh_pc: fh 0x1802E21E0, dev 000000C3
49 2050310 [main] pulseaudio 6196 stat_worker: (\??\C:\Users\Nithin, 0x23A740, 0x1802E21E0), file_attributes 16
133 2050443 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
54 2050497 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: group SID = S-1-5-18
63 2050560 [main] pulseaudio 6196 get_info_from_sd: ACL 0x41FD, uid 1001, gid 18
90 2050650 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::fstat_helper: 0 = fstat (\??\C:\Users\Nithin, 0x23A740) st_size=0, st_mode=0x41FD, st_ino=844424930179137st_atim=5283187B.E70DAEC st_ctim=5283187B.E70DAEC st_mtim=5283187B.E70DAEC st_birthtim=51EB850E.397523D8
63 2050713 [main] pulseaudio 6196 stat_worker: 0 = (\??\C:\Users\Nithin,0x23A740)
203 2050916 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: src /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse
52 2050968 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse = normalize_posix_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
49 2051017 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
54 2051071 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse'
393 2051464 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
62 2051526 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, dst C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, flags 0x4022, rc 0
150 2051676 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0xC0000034 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse)
63 2051739 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0xC0000034 = NtQueryInformationFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse)
101 2051840 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0xC0000034 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse.lnk)
245 2052085 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0xC0000034 = NtQueryInformationFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse.lnk)
57 2052142 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x239310) (0x4022)
56 2052198 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin)
53 2052251 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin'
47 2052298 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
45 2052343 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin, dst C:\Users\Nithin, flags 0x4022, rc 0
133 2052476 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin)
93 2052569 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: not a symlink
100 2052669 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin, 0x239310) (0x4022)
63 2052732 [main] pulseaudio 6196 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse), has_acls(1)
62 2052794 [main] pulseaudio 6196 build_fh_pc: fh 0x1802E21E0, dev 000000C3
946 2053740 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: uid 4294967295, gid 4294967295, attribute 0x800041C0
81 2053821 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
63 2053884 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
58 2053942 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: ACL-Size: 168
135 2054077 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: Created SD-Size: 244
316 2054393 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_file_attribute: 0 = set_file_attribute(\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, -1, -1, 0x800041C0)
195 2054588 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mkdir: 0 = mkdir(/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, 448)
65 2054653 [main] pulseaudio 6196 open: open(/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, 0x148000)
56 2054709 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: src /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse
45 2054754 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse = normalize_posix_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
48 2054802 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
57 2054859 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse'
49 2054908 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
39 2054947 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, dst C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, flags 0x4022, rc 0
140 2055087 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse)
95 2055182 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: not a symlink
90 2055272 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x239310) (0x4022)
59 2055331 [main] pulseaudio 6196 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse), has_acls(1)
63 2055394 [main] pulseaudio 6196 build_fh_pc: fh 0x1802E21E0, dev 000000C3
48 2055442 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::open: (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x148000)
110 2055552 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::set_flags: flags 0x148000, supplied_bin 0x10000
167 2055719 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::set_flags: filemode set to binary
57 2055776 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::open: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (0x280, 0x80100000, \??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, io, NULL, 0x0, 0x7, 0x1, 0x4020, NULL, 0)
59 2055835 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::open: 1 = fhandler_base::open(\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x148000)
70 2055905 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::open_fs: 1 = fhandler_disk_file::open(\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x148000)
55 2055960 [main] pulseaudio 6196 open: 3 = open(/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, 0x148000)
141 2056101 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
50 2056151 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
48 2056199 [main] pulseaudio 6196 get_info_from_sd: ACL 0x41F8, uid 1001, gid 513
85 2056284 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::fstat_helper: 0 = fstat (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x23A720) st_size=0, st_mode=0x41F8, st_ino=31525197391787136st_atim=5283187E.29B8654 st_ctim=5283187E.2BA1B3C st_mtim=5283187E.29B8654 st_birthtim=5283187E.29B8654
104 2056388 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fstat64: 0 = fstat(3, 0x23A720)
94 2056482 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
55 2056537 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
53 2056590 [main] pulseaudio 6196 get_info_from_sd: ACL 0x41F8, uid 1001, gid 513
125 2056715 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: uid 1001, gid 513, attribute 0x41F8
55 2056770 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
53 2056823 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
61 2056884 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: ACL-Size: 168
125 2057009 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: Created SD-Size: 244
550 2057559 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_file_attribute: 0 = set_file_attribute(\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 1001, 513, 0x41F8)
64 2057623 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fchown32: 0 = fchown(/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse,...)
114 2057737 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: uid 4294967295, gid 4294967295, attribute 0x41C0
61 2057798 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
58 2057856 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygsid::debug_print: alloc_sd: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001 (+)
69 2057925 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: ACL-Size: 168
131 2058056 [main] pulseaudio 6196 alloc_sd: Created SD-Size: 244
331 2058387 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_file_attribute: 0 = set_file_attribute(\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, -1, -1, 0x41C0)
73 2058460 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: close(3)
54 2058514 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close: closing '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse' handle 0x280
94 2058608 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: 0 = close(3)
56 2058664 [main] pulseaudio 6196 lstat64: entering
51 2058715 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: src /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse
50 2058765 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse = normalize_posix_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
53 2058818 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
54 2058872 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse'
50 2058922 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
48 2058970 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, dst C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, flags 0x4022, rc 0
128 2059098 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse)
93 2059191 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: not a symlink
49 2059240 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x2394D0) (0x404022)
51 2059291 [main] pulseaudio 6196 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse), has_acls(1)
54 2059345 [main] pulseaudio 6196 build_fh_pc: fh 0x1802E21E0, dev 000000C3
56 2059401 [main] pulseaudio 6196 stat_worker: (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x23A720, 0x1802E21E0), file_attributes 16
131 2059532 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: owner SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
53 2059585 [main] pulseaudio 6196 cygpsid::debug_print: get_sids_info: group SID = S-1-5-21-3177082625-651608231-1113841901-1001
48 2059633 [main] pulseaudio 6196 get_info_from_sd: ACL 0x41F8, uid 1001, gid 513
92 2059725 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::fstat_helper: 0 = fstat (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x23A720) st_size=0, st_mode=0x41F8, st_ino=31525197391787136st_atim=5283187E.29B8654 st_ctim=5283187E.2F725CC st_mtim=5283187E.29B8654 st_birthtim=5283187E.29B8654
62 2059787 [main] pulseaudio 6196 stat_worker: 0 = (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse,0x23A720)
105 2059892 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: src /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse
57 2059949 [main] pulseaudio 6196 normalize_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse = normalize_posix_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
53 2060002 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: conv_to_win32_path (/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
52 2060054 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::cygdrive_win32_path: src '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse', dst 'C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse'
67 2060121 [main] pulseaudio 6196 set_flags: flags: binary (0x2)
47 2060168 [main] pulseaudio 6196 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse, dst C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, flags 0x4022, rc 0
120 2060288 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse)
81 2060369 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: not a symlink
87 2060456 [main] pulseaudio 6196 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, 0x239330) (0x4022)
55 2060511 [main] pulseaudio 6196 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse), has_acls(1)
68 2060579 [main] pulseaudio 6196 build_fh_pc: fh 0x1802E21E0, dev 000000C3
75 2060654 [main] pulseaudio 6196 unlink_nt: Trying to delete \??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, isdir = 1
575 2061229 [main] pulseaudio 6196 unlink_nt: \??\C:\Users\Nithin\.pulse, return status = 0x0
68 2061297 [main] pulseaudio 6196 rmdir: 0 = rmdir(/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse)
498 2061795 [main] pulseaudio 6196 isatty: 1 = isatty(2)
395 2062190 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x236310, 1)
66 2062256 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
63 2062319 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
65 2062384 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
50 2062434 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 1 = write(2, 0x236310, 1)
88 2062522 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x3FE17110D, 2)
49 2062571 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
50 2062621 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
57 2062678 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
50 2062728 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 2 = write(2, 0x3FE17110D, 2)
88 2062816 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x2365C0, 22)
51 2062867 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
51 2062918 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
55 2062973 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
51 2063024 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 22 = write(2, 0x2365C0, 22)
103 2063127 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x3FE171079, 7)
50 2063177 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
52 2063229 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
57 2063286 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
48 2063334 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 7 = write(2, 0x3FE171079, 7)
84 2063418 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x600043B50, 51)
47 2063465 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
48 2063513 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
52 2063565 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
50 2063615 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 51 = write(2, 0x600043B50, 51)
90 2063705 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x3FE17106F, 4)
50 2063755 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
51 2063806 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
54 2063860 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
49 2063909 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 4 = write(2, 0x3FE17106F, 4)
86 2063995 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: pty0, write(0x3FE17111B, 1)
47 2064042 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex (0xB4): waiting -1 ms
66 2064108 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (654): pty output_mutex: acquired
58 2064166 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::write: (669): pty output_mutex(0xB4) released
51 2064217 [main] pulseaudio 6196 write: 1 = write(2, 0x3FE17111B, 1)
2825 2067042 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: close(0)
96 2067138 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1091:  /dev/pty0<0x1802E18F0> usecount + -1 = 2
56 2067194 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
113 2067307 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: 0 = close(0)
1082 2068389 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: close(1)
100 2068489 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close: closing '/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/log.txt' handle 0x224
58 2068547 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: 0 = close(1)
951 2069498 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: close(2)
99 2069597 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1091:  /dev/pty0<0x1802E18F0> usecount + -1 = 1
68 2069665 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
93 2069758 [main] pulseaudio 6196 close: 0 = close(2)
485 2070243 [main] pulseaudio 6196 do_exit: do_exit (256), exit_state 1
57 2070300 [main] pulseaudio 6196 void: 0x0 = signal (20, 0x1)
48 2070348 [main] pulseaudio 6196 void: 0x0 = signal (1, 0x1)
45 2070393 [main] pulseaudio 6196 void: 0x0 = signal (2, 0x1)
46 2070439 [main] pulseaudio 6196 void: 0x0 = signal (3, 0x1)
54 2070493 [main] pulseaudio 6196 init_cygheap::close_ctty: closing cygheap->ctty 0x1802E18F0
48 2070541 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: closing passed in archetype 0x0, usecount 0
49 2070590 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::cleanup: /dev/pty0 closed, usecount 0
49 2070639 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_slave::close: closing last open /dev/pty0 handle
90 2070729 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_console::free_console: freed console, res 1
56 2070785 [main] pulseaudio 6196 fhandler_pty_common::close: pty0 <0xC0,0xC8> closing
55 2070840 [main] pulseaudio 6196 dtable::delete_archetype: deleting element 0 for /dev/pty0(136/0)
58 2070898 [main] pulseaudio 6196 getpid: 6196 = getpid()
51 2070949 [main] pulseaudio 6196 proc_terminate: nprocs 0
48 2070997 [main] pulseaudio 6196 proc_terminate: leaving
68 2071065 [main] pulseaudio 6196 pinfo::exit: Calling ExitProcess n 0x100, exitcode 0x1
```

Please can someone help me?

---

@pabouk  `stat -c "%a %u %g" /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse` gives `770 1001 513` & `775 1001 513` respectively. `stat /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse` gives:

```
File: `/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: 3660e57eh/912319870d    Inode: 4503599627595829  Links: 1
Access: (0770/drwxrwx---)  Uid: ( 1001/  Nithin)   Gid: (  513/    None)
Access: 2013-12-14 13:06:03.981437700 +0530
Modify: 2013-12-14 13:06:03.981437700 +0530
Change: 2013-12-14 13:06:04.587987300 +0530
 Birth: 2013-12-14 13:06:03.981437700 +0530
```

and,

```
  File: `/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: 3660e57eh/912319870d    Inode: 6473924464570479  Links: 1
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/  Nithin)   Gid: (  513/    None)
Access: 2013-12-14 13:08:17.872940100 +0530
Modify: 2013-12-14 13:08:17.872940100 +0530
Change: 2013-12-14 13:08:18.511515200 +0530
 Birth: 2013-12-14 13:08:17.872940100 +0530
```

respectively.

Comment: Try to run the utility with `strace` to see which "syscalls" fail: `strace pulseaudio -vv --start`

Comment: @pabouk I have added the result of strace in my post. Please can you check it?

Comment: I do not see anything new directly showing a problem in the listed output. Was not there a call testing a directory (i.e. `stat()`) or unsuccessful creation of a directory (`mkdir()`)? Unfortunately I do not have any experience with peculiarities of `strace` on Cygwin.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to diagnose this, and PA is WJFFM.  (I'm the Cygwin PA maintainer, FWIW.)  On a hunch, though, do you have a `/dev/shm` directory, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: @pabouk There are a few `stat64()`, `fstat64()`, `lstat64()` and `mkdir()` calls near the end. I've updated my post with these entries. Please check.

Comment: @Yaakov My `/dev/shm` directory is empty. I've added more lines from the `strace` output in my post. According to it, `pulseaudio` is deleting the `~/.pulse` directory. Isn't it abnormal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem until late last year with version 4.0. The latest version from cygwin (5.0) also exhibited this behavior but I found a workaround.

Here is what worked for me:

```
fjardon@yoda 13:22:55 ~
$ export PULSE_STATE_PATH=$HOME/.config/state

fjardon@yoda 13:23:10 ~
$ export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=$HOME/.config/runtime

fjardon@yoda 13:23:19 ~
$ pulseaudio.exe -vvv -p /usr/lib/pulse-5.0/modules -nF /etc/pulse/network.pa
```

The file `/etc/pulse/network.pa` is a copy of the default.pa with two lines to add support for network clients in order to stream the music from my NAS:

```
fjardon@yoda 13:25:16 ~
$ diff /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/network.pa
47a48
> load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1
132a134,138
>
> ### Load DBus protocol
> .ifexists module-dbus-protocol.dll
> load-module module-dbus-protocol
> .endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If the program you are using is not very different from the code in the online repository then it decides to fail on [this if](http://code.google.com/p/pulseaudio/source/browse/src/pulsecore/core-util.c?r=77da2c4bcf843980fe27d4878a468741bdad3a38#289):

```
if (!S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) ||
(st.st_uid != uid) ||
(st.st_gid != gid) ||
((st.st_mode & 0777) != m)) {
errno = EACCES;
goto fail;
}
```

The function `pa_make_secure_dir()` which contains the `if` is being called with these possible combinations of `m`, `uid` and `gid` depending on whether is PA called in system mode (environment variable `PULSE_SYSTEM`) or not:

- `0700`, `-1`, `-1`
- `0755`, `-1`, `-1`

`uid` and `gid` `-1` means that `pa_make_secure_dir()` will use the current owner of the process.

The `fstat()` call returns `st_mode=0x41F8` it is (after applying the mask) `0770` in octal.

### What to try

Try to pre-create the directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse` with mode `0700` or `0755`. You can change it using `chmod`. Also make sure that the owner and group are the same as you run the PA under.

From the code it looks like that the `umask()` call did not have the desired effect and `fchmod()` was not called at all. Is not your home directory on FAT file system or do not you have `noacl` in `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/fstab.d/$USER`? See [File permissions](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html).

### Note

`errno` value of 13 is not "Unknown error" but `EACCESS` - `Permission denied`. There is probably some problem in translating error codes into strings in `pa_cstrerror()`.

Comment: `id` command gives `uid=1001(Nithin) gid=513(None) groups=513(None),545(Users),1002(HomeUsers)`. I tried `mkdir .pulse; chown -R Nithin:None .pulse; chmod -R 0700 .pulse` and `mkdir .pulse; chown -R Nithin:None .pulse; chmod -R 0755 .pulse`. But `pulseaudio -vv` gives the same error in both cases. Also `stat -c %a .pulse` gives `770` and `775`, respectively. My Cygwin home directory is the same as the Windows one and is on NTFS. My `/etc/fstab` contains only `none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0`. My `/etc/fstab.d` directory is empty.

Comment: So `stat -c "%a %u %g" /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse` writes `700 1001 513` in the first test case and `755 1001 513` in the second test case? Also `stat /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin/.pulse` writes that it is a directory? --- Check by `strace` if it does not fail on a different directory this time. (env. variables `PULSE_STATE_PATH` and `PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH`) --- I think without debugging of the code it will be very hard to continue. You can either recompile the program with debugging symbols enabled and use `gdb` or insert control point messages into the code and recompile.

Comment: Please see the output of the commands in my question

Comment: The access rights you showed is not what the software requires (either `0700` or `0755`). See my older note. What does this code write? `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Nithin; rm -rf .pulse; mkdir .pulse; chown -R Nithin:None .pulse; chmod -R 0700 .pulse; stat -c "%a %u %g" .pulse; rm -rf .pulse; mkdir .pulse; chown -R Nithin:None .pulse; chmod -R 0755 .pulse; stat -c "%a %u %g" .pulse` --- You should get: `700 1001 513` / `755 1001 513`

Comment: The output of the command is `770 1001 513` / `775 1001 513`. It seems that `chmod` is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the access to ~/.config directory was the reason.